# Getting a HTTPS connection to work with a local Rails app and nginx?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, https, nginx

I have a Ruby on Rails app that I'm running locally.  I then run a nginx server locally, too.  Now, the connection works fine over HTTP, but when I try to connect over HTTPS, I get the "502 Bad Gateway" error from nginx.  I'm pretty sure the certs are working correctly, because when they weren't, I had a different error, but now something is wrong with my nginx config?  Here's the config:

```
http {
  access_log off;
  #include mime.types;
  default_type application/octet-stream;

  upstream mydomain.com {
    server 127.0.0.1:8080;
  }

  server {
    listen 80;
    server_name local www.local;
    location / {
      proxy_pass http://mydomain.com;
    }
    add_header Pragma "no-cache";
  }

  server {
    listen 443;
    server_name local www.local;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /Users/daise/projects/mydomain/run/ssl/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /Users/daise/projects/mydomain/run/ssl/server.key;
    location / {
      proxy_set_header X-FORWARDED_PROTO https;

      #proxy_pass https://mydomain.herokuapp.com;
      proxy_pass https://mydomain.com;
    }
    add_header Pragma "no-cache";
  }
}
```

I should also add that I spoof my /etc/hosts file to resolve to 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
 proxy_pass https://mydomain.com;
```

to

```
 proxy_pass http://mydomain.com;
```

Your ssl is terminated in nginx. So there is no need to use https to connect to the upstream server.

[**More**]

Also notice a typo in your config file:

```
proxy_set_header X-FORWARDED_PROTO https
```

to

```
proxy_set_header X-FORWARDED-PROTO https;
```